# Adjust div height with image height or how to get height of image with relative URL

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, aem

I am able to retreive image height with absolete URL. But my requirement is to get the image height which I get it from DAM(CMS) for example I need to get the image height present in local dam.

My requirement is i need to set the image as background to my div .SO the div should take height of the image and it should maintain aspect ratio at different break points.So i have used media queries to display different images at different break points.Below is my code.To acheive this i need height of image which is relative url.

```
<div class="box container-fluid" id="bgImageBox" >
     <cq:include path="box-content" resourceType="foundation/components/parsys"/>
</div>
<% 
    java.awt.image.BufferedImage bimg = javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(new java.net.URL("content/dam/marquee/hp-mq-samsung-galaxy-s7-edge-presale-dsktp.jpg"));
     int width_i   = bimg.getWidth();
     int height_i  = bimg.getHeight();
    %>


<style>
#bgImageBox {

    border-color: red;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;
height:<%=height_i%>px;
    }

    @media screen and (min-width: 1px) and (max-width: 723px){
#bgImageBox {
    background-image: url(<%=mobileURL%>);
}
    }


@media  screen and (min-width: 1240px){
 #bgImageBox { background-image: url(<%=desktopUrl%>); }
    }
@media only screen and  (min-width: 940px) and (max-width: 1239px) {

     #bgImageBox { background-image: url(<%=desktopUrl%>); }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 724px) and (max-width: 939px) {

     #bgImageBox { background-image: url(<%=tabletUrl%>); }
}
</style>
```

if i give absolete url to image i am getting height .But if i give relative url to image i am unable to get  height

Comment: You should add additional information regarding what you have tried so far.

Comment: I updatedthe question please go through

Answer (score 0):

You could probably do this in Javascript instead. Using data-attributes you get some nice integration:
HTML:

```
<div class="box container-fluid" data-url="insert_url_here">
    <!-- ... -->
</div>
```

Javascript (using jQuery):

```
$("[data-url]").each(function() {
    var url = $(this).data("url"), img = new Image(), width, height, ratio;

    img.src = url;

    width = img.width;
    height = img.height;
    ratio = width / height;

    var newHeight = $(this).width() / ratio;
    $(this).css({
        "background": "url(" + url + ") no-repeat",
        "background-size": "cover"
        "height": newHeight + "px"});
});
```